# Connect multiple devices to a specific bluetooth server

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I want to connect multiple devices to a single bluetooth server. My application currently makes the server discoverable, and then, the client application lists the discovered devices and tries to connect to one of them. The problem is, I don't know which of the discovered devices is the server. 
The way I am dealing with the problem envolves a try-catch mechanism, where I try to connect to each device and, upon connection, there is a brief message swapping between client and server, where the client asks if the connected device is a server for my application.
The main problem here is that the socket connection and message swapping takes too long, if there are multiple discoverable devices nearby I am forced to probe each one of them asking "are you a server for this app?". Is there any alternative to this system?

Note: There is a little "catch" in this application, there may be multiple servers, so I really need a fast way to go around my device list checking which ones I can connect to.

Comment: please provide some code/pseudocode, it could be useful to understand better the problem

Comment: I don't think this is the case where any code would help, as I am merely asking for opinions / methodologies to solve a problem, I don't have a code problem per se :-)